# Horizontal Bar in Android

Tags: android

This is my first time when i am posting on a forum. Although i am using stackoverflow for a lone time and find it useful.
My question is that i am developing a virtual chemist laboratory! and i have to make a horizontal bar upon which different apparatus can be placed like shown in the picture. Please tell me how to achieve that

[image]

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: Your code ? What have you done so far ? Do you know about Android's `Layouts` , `Activities`, `Widgets` etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LinearLayout and set orientation to horizontal.
Inside this layout add images as much as you wish. 
Use weightSum for linearlayout, also use layout_weight for all images.

Comment: Thanks i got your Idea. Will tell you if it works or not. Anyway Thanks for such a quick reply

Answer (score 0):

- this can be done by FragmentActivity put  horizontal button in main layout and replace fragment 
  firstly create a fragment main layout which has two Items ur horizontal buttons and container for replace fargment  then create fargments according to ur button if u have 4 button the create 4 child fragmentss *
  [check my project](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.Reading.home&hl=en)

Comment: Thankyou for a quick reply. My friend i am not familiar with a fragment activity. Can you explain it more or can suggest another way to do it ?

Comment: Dear this is a simple way one container and replace fargments too simple if u  do not want to use fragments then create  dynamic view  by code "java"  and there is option for add and  remove views and also have option for visibal and invisibal view  for all :) have a nice day and happy new year :)

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use horizontal list view. Its just a simple list view with same adapter support to form list in horizontal orientation.

Check the link for reference https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView

Answer (score 0):

Done with this problem using Linear Layout. and then using a customized border on the bottom side. Then just add horizontal scrollbar in it.
Link : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/54327753/Screenshot%202015-01-02%2022.23.17.png